# Помогите исправить проблему Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Я знакомлюсь с QtDesigner. Я пока просто хочу попробовать добавить пароль в список при нажатии на кнопку "добавить", но возникает ошибка "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)". Не могу понять чем это вызвано. Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

```
import sys
import qdarktheme
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QListWidget, QTextEdit
class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.parol = QTextEdit
        self.list_parols = QListWidget
        self.add = QPushButton
        uic.loadUi('parols.ui', self)
        self.add.clicked.connect(self.ad_item)
    def ad_item(self):
        self.list_parols.addItem(self.parol.text())
if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(qdarktheme.load_stylesheet())
ex = MyWidget()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1. Чтобы получать реальную ошибку, я рекомендую выполнить скрипт в терминале / CMD, так как многие IDE не обрабатывают исключения Qt. 2. Если и после этого вам будет что-то не понятно - предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import qdarktheme
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QListWidget, QTextEdit, QListWidgetItem # !


class MyWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ! Определены в uic.loadUi('parols.ui', self)
        uic.loadUi('parols.ui', self)
        self.add.clicked.connect(self.ad_item)

    def ad_item(self):
        self.list_parols.addItem(QListWidgetItem(self.parol.toPlainText())) # !

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarktheme.load_stylesheet())
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```